# How to hide drop down arrow from combobox in case list size equals 1?

Tags: wpf

I want to display a list with one or more elements. For several elements the natural choice is a combobox. For one element I want it to appear as a textbox. My current solution is to display both, a combobox and a textbox at the same position and hide one of them depending on the number of elements in the list (see below).

I wonder whether there is a more elegant solution, something like to tell the combobox to hide its drop-down arrow in case the list's size equals one.

```
<Grid>
<ComboBox
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding ListSelected}"
    Visibility="{Binding IsList, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToHiddenOrVisibleConverter}}"

/>
<TextBox
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Text="{Binding ListSelected}"
    Visibility="{Binding IsList, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenOrVisibleConverter}}"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the TextBox, and instead change ComboBox's IsEnabled state depending on the number of items inside. On a side note, I believe you actually wanted a TextBlock, not a TextBox, so user can't change the text inside.

So, according to your example and my suggestion:

```
    <ComboBox
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding ListSelected}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsComboEnabled}" />
```

You don't need the Visibility part anymore, since it will always be Visible.

Code behind:

```
public bool IsComboEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return List.Count > 1 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Or, I guess you could make it even easier for yourself. By just overwriting the Visibility property with this (and deleting the TextBox control either way):

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsList}"
```

Comment: Thanks MaxB. TextBlock was indeed my intention. However, a disabled combobox looks much different than a textblock. I want to get rid of the combobox look and feel altogether, because when the list size is 1 it really means there is no list at all.

Comment: I actually tried to find a solution for hiding the drop down arrow on the combo box control before posting my final solution, but everything I found was just too problematic and not worth it. One way is to edit the default ComboBox control, the other is to change system parameter, but I couldn't find a way to bind that system parameter to anything. Either way, let's wait for somebody more capable to do it right

Comment: Thanks, that would confirm I'm doing the right thing.